# возможно ли на js вертикальный календарь?

Tags: javascript, календарь

Как на яваскрипт сгенерировать таблицу календаря где дни идут не в ряд а в столбик?

```
Пн 2 6 16 23 30
Вт
Ср
Чт
Пт
Сб
Вс 1 8 15 22 29
```

Comment: В чем затруднение?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function monthTable(month, year) {
  const monthNames = [
    'Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 
    'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'
  ];

  let calendar =  { 0: ['Вс'], 1: ['Пн'], 2: ['Вт'], 3: ['Ср'], 4: ['Чт'], 5: ['Пт'], 6: ['Сб'] };

  const now = new Date();
  const m = month ? month - 1 : now.getMonth();
  const y = year ? year : now.getFullYear();

  console.log(`${monthNames[m]}, ${y}`);
  console.log();

  const days = new Date(y, m + 1, 0).getDate();

  let week = 1;
  let start = new Date(y, m, 1).getDay();
  for (let i = 0; i < days; i++) {
    if (start % 7 === 1 && i > 0) {
      week++;
    }
    if (calendar[start % 7].length !== week) {
      calendar[start % 7].push('  ');
    }
    if (i < 9) {
      calendar[start % 7].push(` ${i + 1}`);
    } else {
      calendar[start % 7].push(i + 1);
    }
    start++;
  }

  for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    console.log(calendar[i % 7].join(' '));
  }
}

monthTable(5, 2015);
console.log();
monthTable(2, 2020);
console.log();
monthTable();
```